# Java exec() works in IDE but not from .jar

Tags: java, process, jar, exec, runtime.exec

I use the following code to run a batch file and it runs perfectly from the IDE (Netbeans if it matters). I set the working directory (in the run tab of the project properties) to the same directory that I have a built `.jar` file and it works when I run it.

When I clean and build a new jar from the IDE and drag it into the same directory as I set it to run from in the IDE and it doesn't work. I have double checked and it is attempting to use the same command, it just isn't running it.

Is there some flag I need to put in when packaging it, or some security thing Java is using to stop this command?

Here's the code:

```
String command="cmd /c cd \""+System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\bin\"&&"+filename+"";
System.out.println(command);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,command); //How I verify it is the same command
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: See [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) and implement *all* the recommendations.  If doing that in itself does not solve the problem, it will likely provide more information on the failure.  Also, some tips:  1) For 1.5+, use a `ProcessBuilder`. 2) Break the `String command` into `String[] commands` for more robust usage.

Comment: any sort of exception thrown out of this?